# variable not holding output of command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, rhel

The output of $ip coming blank

```
#!/bin/bash
  for i in illinrcmsg{002..003}
  do
  echo " ####################### $i #################### "
  ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $i "
  echo $i
  cp /etc/hosts /etc/hosts_bak
  ip=`ifconfig | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d':' -f2`
  echo $ip
  echo "$ip       $i.corp.amdocs.com      $i" >> /etc/hosts
  "
  done
```

I am trying to fix /etc/hosts entry on multiple servers with a bash script, but it is dumping on hostname values on the file.

Comment: ALso I am using a jump server through which i have passwordless access on all other. I tried another way but not working ip of jump server is getting inserted:
#!/bin/bash
for i in illinrcmsg{002..003}
do
echo " ####################### $i #################### "
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $i "
echo $i
cp /etc/hosts /etc/hosts_bak
echo "`ifconfig | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d':' -f2`     $i.corp.amdocs.com      $i" >> /etc/hosts
"
done

Comment: You are mixing local and remote commands (and variables)

Comment: Thankyou @hek2mgl found my mistake

Answer (score -1):

This worked:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in illinrcmsg{002..003}
do
echo " ####################### $i #################### "
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $i "
echo $i
cp /etc/hosts /etc/hosts_bak
#ip=`ifconfig | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d':' -f2`
#echo $ip
echo "`nslookup illinrcmsg002 | tail -n 2 | head -n 1|awk '{print $2}'` 
$i.corp.amdocs.com      $i" >> /etc/hosts
"
done
```